# Inserir vários html com ajax

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código em jquery:

```
musicas: function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/includes/oloco.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            efeito.inicio();
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.texto').html(data[0].musica);
            efeito.fim();
        }
    }),
    setTimeout(function(){
        player.musicas();
    }, 15000);
}
```

E no html como visto tenho:

```
 <div class="text"></div>
```

Porém, meu ajax atual só muda o texto da div, gostaria de adicionar 5 divs mudando o data[]!
A requisição oloco.php é em json e tem exatamente 5 valores como podem ver a seguir:

```
[
{
    "musica": "Luan Santana  Acordando o Pr\u00e9dio - Make U Sweat Remix (Lyric Video)"
},
{
    "musica": "Kygo ft. Parson James - Stole the show (Lyrics video)"
},
{
    "musica": "Justin Bieber Ft Daddy Yankee y Luis Fonsi - Pasito a Pasito Suave Suavecito (Letras)"
},
{
    "musica": "Jhef - Vida M\u00edtica (Official V\u00eddeo)"
},
{
    "musica": "Jhef - Pode ser n\u00f3s dois (Official Video)"
}
]
```

Como posso inserir várias divs com os valores diferentes e em ordem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você iterar sobre o resultado da requisição AJAX e utilizar a função `append` do jQuery para inserir o elemento no DOM. Deve ficar parecido com isso:

```
musicas: function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/includes/oloco.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            efeito.inicio();
        },
        success: function(data){

            // Exclui possíveis músicas anteriores:
            $('.texto').html("");

            // Itera sobre todos os elementos de data:
            $(data).each(i => {
                // Cria um novo elemento p:
                let element = $("<p>");
                // Define o conteúdo de p:
                element.html(data[i].musica);
                // Adiciona o novo elemento ao DOM:
                $('.texto').append(element);
            });

            efeito.fim();
        }
    }),
    setTimeout(function(){
        player.musicas();
    }, 15000);
}
```

Comment: E como posso apenas atualizar no setTimeout invez de adicionar mais divs?

Comment: Como assim? Você quer que a cada 15 minutos seja adicionada uma música?

Comment: Dessa forma a cada 15 minutos adiciona novas <p> com as mesmas músicas, entende? Gostaria que adicionasse apenas ao entrar no site e depois só atualizar o conteudo das mesmas...

Comment: Não está suficientemente claro ainda. Você quer que, quando acessado a página, sejam inseridas as 5 músicas e depois de 15 minutos essas músicas mudem para as novas que retornarem da requisição AJAX?

Comment: É assim, são 5 músicas, porém elas atualizam os nomes a cada certo tempo... Com o append são adicionadas 5 divs a cada 15 segundos, resultando inúmeros textos... Quero que a partir da primeira vez adicionado apenas atualize o seu conteudo (html) invez de continuar acionando....

Comment: A cada 15s está inserindo novas divs ocasionando isso: http://prnt.sc/f5o0za

Comment: Depois de inserido ao entrar no site quero apenas atualizar os conteúdo das mesmas (ao invez de adicionar novas com o append)...

Comment: Entendido. Editei a resposta para corrigir isto.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção amigo, vc é show.

Comment: Acredito que este código já fará isso, irá atualizar sem adicionar.
Esse trecho garante isso:
// Exclui possíveis músicas anteriores:
$('.texto').html("");